# How to interrupt Monitor.Enter

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have two threads that compete over a single resource, but frequently either thread is required to perform some other tasks. Is there a mechanism available that [**1.** allows me to acquire an exclusive lock] but [**2.** can be interrupted while it is waiting]

I would prefer to avoid timeouts (i.e. Monitor.TryEnter) to minimize time overhead.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you have the freedom to step back and rethink this look at ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent.    In Short can you create a different sharing mechanism such as a queue or task based such that the threads are not required to break into each others running work. (Or why does thread 1 need to exclusively lock it for so long).  Can you shift the burden to the constrained resource so the threads each try and wait at the same time.   Or is each of your two threads really 4 threads. Thread 1 is really MainThread1a and WorkerThread1b.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm using **SemaphoreSlim**:

```
semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken)
```